# setInterval using ajax and a specific target function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "chat.php",
        data: {fn: 'set_interval'}, 
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

}, 10000);
```

**chat.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['fn'])){
    $fn = $_POST['fn'];
    $fn();
}

function set_interval(){
    echo 'done';
}
```

Console says: - `Undefined index: fn...`

I'm expecting `done` in console.

Comment: perhaps try and change `type` to `"post"` and then use `if(isset($_POST['fn']))` if you want to use post, change `$_POST` to `$_GET` if you want to use get...

Comment: you are using `GET` but checking `$_POST`...

Comment: You are checking GET put retieve the value using POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `POST` to `GET` -

```
if(isset($_GET['fn'])){
    $fn = $_GET['fn'];
    $fn();
}
```

Comment: My pleasure :) @qadenza